# Change of reference frame for a wavefunction: same modulus but different currents?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, wavefunction, rotation, unitarity

Suppose that, at a certain $t=0$, one has a wavefunction 
$$
    \psi=\psi(x,y)
$$
defined on a plane and well normalized to $1$. Coordinates (x,y) refer to the frame $xOy$.

How does the wavefunction change if, at time $t=0$, one jumps on a rotating frame $x\prime O\prime y\prime $ such that

1. The origin coincides with that of the initial frame (i.e, $O\,\equiv \, O^\prime$);
2. At time $t=0$, $x \, \equiv x^\prime$ and $y \, \equiv \, y^\prime$;
3. The second reference frame has angular velocity $\Omega$ with respect to the first one.

N.B. 1: I'm not interested in the wavefunction at different times, i.e. for $t>0$, but just in 
$$
  \psi'=\psi'(x',y')
$$
at $t=0$.

N.B. 2: I expect (please correct me if I am wromg) $\psi$ and $\psi^\prime$ to be such that $|\psi|^2=|\psi^\prime|^2$ but their phases should be different because the *currents*, e.g. the probability current
$$
   \vec{j}= \frac{\hbar}{2mi}(\psi^*\nabla\psi-\psi\nabla\psi^*)
$$
should be different in the two frames.

Comment: $\begin{aligned}x\mapsto x\cos \left( \Omega \,t\right) -y\sin \left( \Omega \, t\right) \\
y\mapsto x\,\sin\left( \Omega \, t\right) +y\,\cos\left( \Omega t\right) \end{aligned}$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't think this transformation is enough... because at $t=0$ the two wavefunctions, $\psi$ and $\psi^\prime$ would coincide. I agree that the square moduli of $\psi$ and $\psi^\prime$ should coincide at $t=0$, but there should be something different in their *phases*. Namely, their phases should be different because the *currents* measured in the two frames should be different.

Answer (score 2):

Change of coordinate system in quantum mechanics can be easily done in Heisenberg approach of quantum mechanics. You can very easily transform(as I will demonstrate below) the Hamiltonian from one frame of reference to the other and then plug this new Hamiltonian in Schrodinger equation to find the transformed wavefunctions.

Hamiltonian in the rest/ground frame- $H$

Hamiltonian in rotation frame(rotating with angular velocity $\Omega$) - $H_{rot}$

$H_{rot} = UHU^\dagger -iU\frac{dU^\dagger}{dt}$

where $U$ is the transformation operator. $U = e^{-i\Omega tJ_z }$

else, $\phi_{rot}(t) = e^{-i\Omega t J_z}\phi(t)$

where $J_z$ is the $z$-component of total angular momentum for rotation about the $z$-axis with angular velocity $\Omega$.

Comment: If you take for example the harmonic oszillazor hamiltonian as an example, what is sigma z in that case? Also what would H rot be then?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Anyway, I fear you haven’t answered my question. I’m interested in how the wave function modifies, not in the Hamiltonian. Moreover, at t=0, the transformation you’ve proposed reduces to the identity, which -I think- is wrong.

Comment: @AndreaPaco As rotation is quantized in quantum mechanics. Wavefunction in rotation frame will be $\phi_{rot}(t) = e^{-i\Omega t L_z}\phi(t)$. $L_z$ can be matrix if you have finite dimensions or $L_z=xp_y-yp_x$ if you have infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: @lalala for quantum harmonic oscillator $U=e^{i\Omega t L_z}$ where $L_z= xp_y-y_px$. You can do the rest of the maths.

Comment: @Jitendra, thanks. But, at t=0, the wave functions are the same in the two frames, which I think it is not correct. Do you agree?

Comment: Thanks. Of course. I didnt think to call the angular momentum operater as pauli matrix; but it makes sense.

Comment: @AndreaPaco at t=0 $\phi_{rot}(0) = e^{-i\Omega L_z (0)}\phi(0) = \phi(0)$. At t=0 wavefunctions should coincide, where is the problem?

Comment: For me, the fact that the wavefunctions coincide at t=0 is counterintuitive. It is a matter of *currents*: is something (e.g. a vortex) is rotating in a certain frame, it should rotate with a different angular frequency in another frame.

Comment: Additionally, take another example: a frame which is translating with respect to another. If a certain wave packet has a certain group velocity in a frame, I expect this group velocity to be different in the other (inertial) frame.

Comment: @AndreaPaco As all the transformations used in physics are continuous and differentiable, so according to boundary conditions, the wavefunctions at t=0 should coincide. Of course, you are right that in the rotating frame the angular velocity will be different but at t=0 there is no effect of transformations, so wavefunctions coincide in both frames.

In the case of translation, you can just replace the angular momentum from linear momentum. 
You may remember from elementary quantum mechanics that linear momentum is a generator of translation and angular momentum is a generator of rotation.

Comment: Yes, i remember that momentum is the generator of translation and angular momentum is the generator of translations. So, if the wave functions are the same in the two frames, how can I mathematically compute that the angular velocities are different? In view of this, I am not sure that the unitary transformation $U$ that you’ve mentioned (although correct!!) plays the role of frame’s changer: indeed I am not sure that the concept “unitary operation that performs a rotation” corresponds to the concept “reference frame transformation”.

Comment: All I said was that at t=0 wavefunctions will coincide. At a later time t, the wavefunctions will definitely change. 

Just multiply your static frame wavefunction with $e^{-i\Omega L_zt}$ and you will get your rotating frame wavefunction. ($\phi_{rot} = U\phi$).

Comment: I thank you again for your interest in my question. I'm sorry, but your explanation does not fully convince me. For me it's very strange that, at $t=0$ the wavefunctions in the two frames coincide. As I said (and you agreed with me) the angular momentum measured in the two frames should be different, also at $t=0$.